# Titlerule and Wrapfig Interaction

Tags: titlesec, wrapfigure

Hey y'all I need some help! I would like to have my section headers have a titlerule underneath, but titlerule isn't playing nice with wrapfig.

I'm using `wrapfig` and `tcolorbox` to make a sidebar, and `titlesec` to add the rule underneath the section header. The text itself is wrapping just fine around the sidebar, but the `\titlerule` is going straight through the sidebar!

Here's my MWE:

```
Preamble
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, tmargin=0.5in, marginparwidth=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    %Part of sidebars
\usepackage{tcolorbox}                  %Other part of sidebars
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %Change chap/sec/ssec layout
\usepackage{blindtext}                  %MWE text

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\newenvironment{Sidebar}
   {\wrapfigure{r}{0.43\textwidth}\vspace{-3em}\tcolorbox[colframe=black!50!white]\footnotesize}
   {\endtcolorbox\vspace{2em}\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Look, a Chapter!}
\blindtext

\begin{Sidebar}
{\centering\bfseries Title \\[0.5em]}
\blindtext[1]
\end{Sidebar}
\section{Now a section!}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the titlerule isn't stopping where the text stops. Any insight you can give would be greatly appreciated!

[image: MWEImage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: add an empty box before `\titlerule` and a negative vertical skip to make up for the vertical space thus added:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, tmargin=0.5in, marginparwidth=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Part of sidebars
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %Other part of sidebars
\usepackage{titlesec} %Change chap/sec/ssec layout
\usepackage{blindtext} %MWE text

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}[\vskip-1.5ex\mbox{}{}\titlerule]

\newenvironment{Sidebar}
   {\wrapfigure{r}{0.43\textwidth}\vspace{-3em}\tcolorbox[colframe=black!50!white]\footnotesize}
   {\endtcolorbox\vspace{2em}\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Look, a Chapter!}
\blindtext

\begin{Sidebar}
{\centering\bfseries Title \\[0.5em]}
\blindtext[1]
\end{Sidebar}

\setlength\linewidth{0.57\textwidth}

\section{Now a section!}
\setlength\rightskip{0pt}
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]